# SQL Server split time intervals of Overnight employees to multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, time, split

```
CREATE TABLE workingSchedule 
(
    [workingDate] DATETIME NULL,
    [openTime]    TIME(7) NULL,
    [closeTime]   TIME(7) NULL
);

INSERT INTO workingSchedule (workingDate, openTime, closeTime)
VALUES ('10/1/2015','23:00','00:00'),
       ('10/2/2015','00:00','07:00'),
       ('10/2/2015','23:00','00:00'),
       ('10/3/2015','00:00','07:00');

CREATE TABLE breakTable 
(
    [breakDate] DATETIME NULL,
    [breakStart] TIME NULL,
    [breakEnd] TIME NULL
);

INSERT INTO breakTable (breakDate, breakStart, breakEnd)
VALUES ('10/1/2015','23:30','23:45'),
       ('10/2/2015','00:00','00:30'),
       ('10/2/2015','03:00','03:15'),
       ('10/2/2015','23:00','07:00'); --- this is as a holiday
```

I am trying to split the time intervals in `[workingSchedule]` into several rows considering the `[breakTable]`. The result I desire looks like this:

```
Date          Start    End  
----------------------------
10/1/2015     23:00    23:30  
10/1/2015     23:45    00:00  
10/1/2015     00:30    03:00  
10/2/2015     03:15    07:00  
10/2/2015     00:00    08:00
```

The last break is to show the 8 hours of holiday as an example as those scenarios can occur.

Tried the following however it only works for day employees - I need help trying to relate the related breaks to the working schedule dates and time interval associated:

```
SELECT  
    workingDate AS [date], openTime AS [Start], 
    COALESCE(breakStart, closeTime) AS [End]
FROM    
    workingSchedule
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT  
         breakDate, breakStart, breakEnd, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY breakDate ORDER BY breakStart) AS ROWNUM
     FROM    
         breakTable) AS firstBreak ON workingSchedule.workingDate = firstBreak.breakDate 
                                   AND firstBreak.ROWNUM = 1

UNION

SELECT  
    breakStart.breakDate, breakStart.breakEnd,   
    COALESCE(breakEnd.breakStart, endTime.closeTime)
FROM    
    (SELECT  
         breakDate, breakStart, breakEnd, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY breakDate ORDER BY breakStart) AS ROWNUM
     FROM    
         breakTable) AS breakStart
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT  
         breakDate, breakStart, breakEnd, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY breakDate ORDER BY breakStart) AS ROWNUM
     FROM    
         breakTable) AS breakEnd ON breakStart.breakDate = breakEnd.breakDate 
                                 AND breakStart.ROWNUM = breakEnd.ROWNUM - 1
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT  
         workingDate, closeTime
     FROM    
         workingSchedule) AS endTime ON breakStart.breakDate = endTime.workingDate
```